# Connecting to a MS Access database through a function

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, vba, module

This is my function:

```
Public Function DBConnection(ByVal path As String)
    ' This function makes the database connection and returns the object
    ' to reference it.
    cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path + ";")
    cn.Open()
    Return cn
End Function
```

As you can see, I want to initialize a database connection and return it so I can use it in my forms. This function is in a module and my variables are as follows:

```
Public cn As OleDbConnection
Public cmd As OleDbCommand
Public dr As OleDbDataReader
```

But I'm not sure how I can use this in my forms, do I just call the function `DBConnection` and then proceed with my SQL statements? Or do I have to do something else? Help would be very much appreciated, cheers.

Also, I need some opinions. My application relies on a MS Access database. Is it better to initialize the connection on `Form_Load` and then close the connection when the user closes the program, or open and close the connections as the queries are run? I'm planning to use some database queries on multiple forms hence the reason I was putting it into a module, but I'm not 100% on how I should proceed with this.

Thanks.

Comment: is your client application a .NET app or is it a separate access application?

Answer (score 1):

From: [`How to bind Microsoft Access forms to ADO recordsets`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998/EN-US/)

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

   'Use the ADO connection that Access uses
   Set cn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection

   'Create an instance of the ADO Recordset class, and
   'set its properties
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
   With rs
      Set .ActiveConnection = cn
      .Source = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
      .LockType = adLockOptimistic
      .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
      .Open 
   End With

   'Set the form's Recordset property to the ADO recordset
   Set Me.Recordset = rs

   Set rs = Nothing
   Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.  That function will open a connection every time it's called.  You better make sure you are closing the database as well, or that will start eating up memory.

You might look at some other options (such as using NHibernate or another ORM.)

However, if you stay with this model, you could then use the cn that is returned to access your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this function will only be called once in the program, on `Form_Load`. When I use the cn that's returned do I just use it in the normal way? Like when I want to run a query I just use `cmd = New OleDbCommand("blah")`?

Comment: Yeah, instead of creating a new connection, you would just use cn, so something like cn.Query() or whatever function calls you need to use.